# Get related posts to custom post type, with Advanced Custom Fields Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I am having an issue I can't seem to fix.

Right now I have a working product filter with WP_Query using arguments.
But I want to extend this filter more with a custom post type.

With ACF I created a Related field > Post Object. 
My products (smartphone accessories) belong to a custom post type (smartphone model). So in the admin I can select which device can be used with the product.

For example for "Cover A" I have selected "Smartphone 5X".
I have set $smartphone to be "Smartphone 5X".
Now in my arguments I'd like to say something like:

```
$args = array(
'post_type'      => 'product',
'post_model'     => $smartphone );
```

But this of course does not work.
I tried checking with ACF: [ACF Documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/) but I can't seem to find the solution.

I managed to show the model in the product page, but I want to do the filter earlier so my $products->found_posts will still give the right number.

Anyone who can point me in the right direction?